# Is it a good practice to use tight coupling between custom directive and $scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**The expected behavior:** When custom directive is attached to `iframe`, it should listen for `onload` event and when iframe contents is loaded, it should inform `$scope` about that.

Currently, I'm using the following code for directive:

```
app.directive('iframeOnload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.on('load', function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.iframeIsLoaded = true;
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, a tight coupling is created between `$scope` and `iframeOnload` directive, and I'm wondering if that's okay?

Any improvements suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Modifying the code above is based on what you want to achieve. Where you need this flag   
` $scope.iframeIsLoaded` etc ...

Comment: In one of my controllers, in which context custom directive is used.

Comment: You can emit an event and listen to it in your controller and do the staff which needs this flag to be true in your event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a good practice. But you can handle it by passing an action as a directive parameter.

So the directive can be called passing a function from the controller handling your desired result.

```
<iframe ... iframe-onload="iframeDidLoad()"></iframe>
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive('iframeOnload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            iframeOnload: '&'
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.on('load', function(e) {
                if($scope.iframeOnload) {

                    $scope.$apply(function () {                     
                        $scope.iframeOnload();
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: need to keep `$apply()` or  or other method to tell angular to run digest..event is outside of angular context

Comment: Imho for such directives it is better not to use isolated scope.

Comment: @charlietfl you are right, when scope operations are needed inside the callback function, it requires a digest to propperly apply the operations on scope. It could be done inside the callback but is better apply from within the directive. Anyways, updated the answer.